# Black screen with cursor after logging out of guest account on High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, login-screen, sip

When I log out of my guest account, it gets stuck with a black screen and a cursor that I can move around but can't do anything except do a forced restart. In my searching, I have seen an [old recommendation](http://markedmondson.me/osx-black-screen-no-login-screen-but-with-working-cursor-on-boot-fixed) to remove the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist` file (that didn't work for me). I've also seen that someone [disabled System Integrity Protection](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8161712) with `csrutil disable`.

I looked in the Console after restarting and saw the following line:

```
Apr 24 12:45:55 my-computer com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] 
 (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.201.100028.Aqua):
 Caller not allowed to perform action: loginwindow.1627,
 action = service removal, code = 150:
 Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged,
 uid = 0, euid = 201, gid = 201, egid = 201, asid = 100028
```

This mentions both loginwindow and System Integrity Protection. Is disabling SIP the only way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How I solved this issue on Mac OS 10.13 High Sierra:

- Boot into Recovery Mode (Command-R)
- Open Terminal, disable SIP (csrutil disable), restart
- Login to Guest, logout (it should not hang on a black screen now)
- Boot into Recovery Mode (Command-R)
- Open Terminal, enable SIP (csrutil enable), restart
- Login to Guest, logout (it still works!)

Comment: Wow, thanks that worked for me too! I did have to shut down in between some of those steps instead of restarting because it was not rebooting correctly, but it did eventually work.

Comment: Worked for me in Mojave too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in Mojave.  Disabling SIP with 'csrutil disable' solved the problem for me, although that doesn't reflect well on Apple or MacOS.